# How do I fix this error after assigning driver object to "new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, caps)" from multiple instances in a thread?

Tags: java, appium-android

I've created a little script for testing a few elements in my app with `Appium`. I've set-up my project accordingly, tried to run it with only one device and `Appium server`, works like a charm. If I run it again with multiple devices and respectful servers, many problems appear. Some devices do not run the app at all, some devices run the app but not the script while only one random device out of all of them runs the script.

I am running the command-line Appium version like this:

`> appium -p XXXX -bp XXX --session-override`

...where -p defines the server's port while -bp defines the bootstrap port. They are both different for each server.

The way my code works is that I've set up a class object for each device I define in my main code so that all of them can get tested simultaneously via separate threads for each of them.

**Using breakpoints, I've found out that this line in my code has caused the following error:**

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception: Error in building: Ill-formed XML document (multiple root elements detected). Try changing the 'normalizeTagNames' driver setting to 'true' in order to workaround the problem.
```

**This is what caused it:**
`driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(url, capabilities);`

---

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    private static String[][] testArgs = {

            {"Device-1", "my-udid-01", "8.0.0", "http://0.0.0.0:5000/wd/hub"},
            {"Device-2", "my-udid-02", "9", "http://0.0.0.0:5001/wd/hub"},
            {"Device-3", "my-udid-03", "9", "http://0.0.0.0:5002/wd/hub"}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(final String[] testArgs : testArgs) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    new TestScript(testArgs);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        // If this function stops, then all threads will stop working. I chose to end the script 
        // at my will by stopping the code.
        while(true){}
    }
}
```

**TestScript.java**

```
class TestScript {

    private RemoteWebDriver driver;

    TestScript(String[] args) {

        try {

            String deviceName = args[0];

            DesiredCapabilities caps1 = new DesiredCapabilities();

            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, args[1]);
            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, args[2]);
            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, deviceName);
            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "my-app.apk");
            caps1.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UIAutomator2");

            // This is what triggers the error
            driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL(args[3]), caps1);

            run(deviceName);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            driver = null;
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void run(String deviceName) {

        //... The testing goes here and does not cause any problem...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this?